# Assign title bar double click action to fill entire screen except unity panel and launcher

Tags: unity, window, window-buttons

I'm currently using 12.04.1 64-bit. I prefer to use the title bar action buttons (min/max/close) on right side. Sure I can make them appear on right side from **Ubuntu Tweak** but it wont work in full screen mode. Shifting between right and left is lot of pain and is one of the main issues preventing me from using Ubuntu.

There is already a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/772212).
It affects many people. I believe these kind of settings needs to be versatile, but seems there is nothing much can be done till Unity adds this feature.

I would request for a similar alternate solution which I think is definitely possible.

What I want is when I double click on a title bar, the window shouldn't maximize, instead it should fill the entire screen excluding launcher and Unity panel.

I actually used something similar to this in **Compiz Configuration Settings Manager**, where desktop binding to the top had filled the screen. But I couldn't find it in Compiz now, maybe it has upgraded.

Please provide a solution for assigning title bar double click to fill screen excluding launcher and unity panel, *so that* I can have the action buttons on right side always.